# Unable to drop existing master table in sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, datapump

I was using yeasterday many times Data Pump in Sql Developer Wizard to export and import data. After each export/import a new master table appeared under the "+" button in sql developer(view->dba). 
I wanted to drop all this tables(about 10 tables) and I was successfull for all cases, except 2 of them. When I'm writing sql code: drop table x, it shows me error that this tables doesn't exists. It was working fine for every others tables..
When i run query select * from dba_tables where table_name='x' the table is there. I'm writing drop statement as system user.

```
  select * 
      from dba_tables 
     where table_name in ('moj_dump_job'
                        , 'moj_job_data_pump');


OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                    
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYSTEM                         moj_dump_job                  
SYSTEM                         moj_job_data_pump             

drop table moj_dump_job;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
drop table moj_dump_job
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I tired to drop this jobs, but it doesnt't work:

```
select owner_name, job_name
  from DBA_DATAPUMP_JOBS;

OWNER_NAME                     JOB_NAME                      
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYSTEM                         moj_job_data_pump             
SYSTEM                         moj_dump_job    


BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name => 'moj_dump_job');
END;

Error starting at line : 13 in command -
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name => 'moj_dump_job');
END;
Error report -
ORA-27475: "SYSTEM.MOJ_DUMP_JOB" must be a job
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 213
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 657
ORA-06512: at line 2
27475. 00000 -  "unknown %s \"%s\".\"%s\""
*Cause:    The specified object did not exist, privileges were not granted,
           or the object was of the wrong type.
*Action:   Specify an object of the correct type on which you have privileges.
```

Do you have any idea what can I do? Using schema name before table name doesn't help.
Best regards, Darek

Comment: how are you running this? is this code part of any procedure?

Comment: It is most likely to do with the names being created in lowercase. But, why the heck did someone (or you) create tables and jobs under `SYSTEM` schema? It is not for creating user's tables. Simply, move them to other schemas owned by non-admin login user.

Comment: did you try to drop it as SYSTEM user?

Comment: Does `drop table "moj_dump_job";` help (i.e. enclosing table name into double quotes)?

Comment: @AmitNaik No, it's not part of any procedure. I'm running it separatly as single statement.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - this job and tables are created automatically when you are using Data Pump Wizard. If it would have something in common with lowercase i should see in dictionary table names with lowercase. But i will try :)

Comment: @hotfix yes, as i sad in the problem description

Comment: @Littlefoot see my answer to Kaushik Nayak

Comment: @drk can you run this `BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name => '"moj_dump_job"');
END` ? see if this runs

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your help. It work's.

```
drop table "moj_dump_job"
drop table "moj_job_data_pump";


Table "moj_dump_job" dropped.
Table "moj_job_data_pump" dropped.
```

Now

```
 select * 
   from dba_tables 
  where table_name in ('moj_dump_job'
                     , 'moj_job_data_pump');


select owner_name, job_name
  from DBA_DATAPUMP_JOBS;
```

Both statements doesn't return any rows. That's perfect, but the 2 tables are still visible under view ->dba ->data pump -> export jobs. How to drop them from the tree?

Comment: Ok, I have found the solution. I have deleted .dmp and .log file from the location where they were stored on my Windows system.

Comment: Now that it is clear to you, also pay attention to my second point. Don't allow user tables to be created in `SYSTEM` schema.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was not working cause by default Oracle changes job name to uppercase. To avoid it need use `'"my_job"'`

As per Oracle doc

> Follow SQL naming rules to name Scheduler objects in the
>   DBMS_SCHEDULER package. By default, Scheduler object names are
>   uppercase unless they are surrounded by double quotes. For example,
>   when creating a job, job_name => 'my_job' is the same as job_name =>
>   'My_Job' and job_name => 'MY_JOB', but different from job_name =>
>   '"my_job"'. These naming rules are also followed in those cases where
>   comma-delimited lists of Scheduler object names are used within the
>   DBMS_SCHEDULER package.